# How do you map a HasOne relationship with nHibernate Fluent mapping and avoid N+1?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have 2 tables **ATable** and **AATable** where both have a shared Primary Key - **ATable.aKey** and **AATable.aKey** to represent a one-to-one relationship. For my Fluent mapping I have a HasOne Relationship defined within my Fluent ATableMapping, all of which works fine. However I have noticed that querying for **ATable** generates a 2nd query (N+1) for the child Table **AATable**.  My understanding is that Hasone eager loads by default, and I had assumed this would be part of the query for ATable, but I may well have this wrong?

I have researched various solutions including using .Not.LazyLoad().Fetch.Join(), PropertyRef, ForeignKey but I cannot seem to resolve the n+1 so that either it is Eager loaded with 1 query, or Lazy loaded and I can fetch the child with my queries.

Has anyone had any issues with this or have an example they know to work with no n+1?  Grateful for any advice.

Answer (score -2):

You have two options:

1. `Not.LazyLoad()` which disables possibility to provide lazy loaded related entity and it would enforce NHB to provide corresponding `subselect` within original query
2. Use `component mapping` so both entities point to the same table. This is better approach as once you decided to fetch both entities together, generated queries hit only one table - not two like within first option. This is definitely better for performance.

Comment: Hi, I am aware of the solution to merge tables, but we wanted to avoid this as the tables already exist, and ideally we want seperate tables.  Re .Not.LazyLoad this has no effect - three is still a query for the second table.  The child record is optional and not available in this test - could this be a factor?

Comment: You should consider to merge those tables because of performance gain. Have you tried to use HQL along with `left join fetch` and enforce only one query?

Comment: Hi, considering the merge now, but I would like to know what is going wrong here for future ref.  I can happily fetch the child table in my queries and left joins are correctly being generated, but the problem is that HasOne is forcing an eager load/second query.  I've tried Fetch.Join in my mapping but it does nothing ?!  Effectively this would make HasOne useless.  I can't for force HasOne to lazyLoad and Eager gives N+1.  Frustrated :)

Comment: Well, I think that this confusion you have right now forced us to use component mapping at the end of our struggle :-)